# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: xcode

"A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."  Is what it says.  The device I am trying to test on worked in the past and shows up in the developer certificate section, and in the Xcode organizer.  I've tried following similar stack overflow questions, which have had me doing a lot of confusing things like deleting profiles or certificates, but nothing is working. I'm worried I've somehow made things worse.

I can use the Organizer to view the device just fine, and can see that it has a provisioning profile.

I can use a completely new device to connect, and it is added in Xcode and in the developer center, and it still says that my application can't run on the device.

In organizer, when I click on the device, it shows two applications, one of which is the old name of the application I am trying to run (with the old icon). Not sure if this is relevant.

If I go to the new device, it has no applications at all listed.

I have no idea what to do.

Edit:

I made another test application, added it's app id in apple developer, made a provisioning profile for it, installed the profile on the device, and was able to run just fine.   I followed the exact same steps I had used to re-make a provisioning profile for the original app (even confirming by making a new profile and reprovisioning)

So...something's wrong with the original app, but not xcode or the device(s) in question.

I deleted EVERY development profile besides the test one that worked on a different app.  I made a new development profile that was as identical to the distribution profile (which still works) as possible.  I deleted all old profiles in xcode, and on the device.  I tried to run on the device and it still didn't work.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Edit:

I have found a potential problem, that I am trying to solve.  My distribution certificate (which works) has my current last name, but my development certificate has my maiden name (I was married between making my account and distributing my app, and had to do name change things with apple). Is it possible it's an error on their end.  When I view the certificate on the developer website it has the correct name, but when I download it the name is incorrect.

But...wait... If it were the certificates fault, wouldn't it also not work for my other test app's development profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did turn out that it was the fault of my last name changing between generating the development certificate and generating the distribution certificate.  The certificate itself was valid, and had two months until it expired, but apparently having the wrong name messed stuff up.

I deleted the certificate locally. I revoked it on the developer site.  That fixed things.  (I HAD made an entirely new certificate and attached it to the broken app, but until I revoked the old one it didn't work).

I have NO idea why a certificate problem only effected the app created with my old last name and not the new test app.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your certificates are all valid and properly installed and that your devices are all properly registered, the most likely cause is a mismatch between the App ID in the provisioning profile and the Bundle Identifier in the application.  Go to your provisioning profile and see what App Id it is associated with.  The Bundle Identifier in the application Target in Xcode must match this App Id.  If the App Id contains a wild card (for example *com.mydomain.** then the Bundle Identifier must be *com.mydomain.anything*.  If the App Id does not contain a wild card then the Bundle Identifier must match exactly.

If the App Id and Bundle Identifier don't match then you will need to either change the Bundle Identifier or create a new Provisioning Profile using an App Id that matches the Bundle Identifier in your project.

Comment: When I went to developer.apple.com, I saw that the app ID was the xcode ios wildcard id.  I changed it to be EXACTLY what it was in my bundle identifier.  I then went to xcode organizer and refreshed my provisioning profiles.  I deleted the old profile from my device (from organizer as well), and added the new one.  Unfortunately, I still got the same error when I tried to run. That IS something I hadn't tried yet, though, so I was pretty hopeful.

Comment: Are you sure the certificate and provisioning profile are for development and not distribution? Also are the devices properly associated with the provisioning profile?

Comment: Yes, I have both a development and a distribution profile, and make sure to choose "development".  I see the two devices I have tested with in the profile online, and in Xcode organizer I see the profile under the device section correctly.  I am so confused -.-